# Compute the eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors for $ T $

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F^2}, \mathbb{F^2}) $ be defined by
$$ T(u, v) = (v, u) $$
for every $ u, v \in \mathbb{F} $. Compute the eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors for $ T $.

To compute the eigenvalues I proceeded with the following steps:
$$ T(u, v) = (v, u) = \lambda(u, v) $$
$$ v = \lambda u $$
$$ u = \lambda v $$
Substituting:
$$ v = \lambda \cdot \lambda v $$
$$ 1 = \lambda^2 $$
$$ \pm 1 = \lambda $$

However, I don't know how to proceed from here to find the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the eigenvectors, write down, for each eigenvalue $\lambda$, the equation $T(u,v)=\lambda(u,v)$.

In the case of $\lambda=1$, you get the equation $$T(u,v)=1\cdot (u,v)\\
(v,u)=(u,v)$$

which means every vector for which $u=v$ is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that eigenvalues will satisfy $\lambda^2=1$, but you cannot yet conclude that they are $1$ and $-1$. It could be just $1$ (with multiplicity $2$) or just $-1$ (with multiplicity $2$).

Let us go back to an earlier step and try the two possible candidates for $\lambda$, to see if both $-1$ and $1$ work or if only one works.

- $\lambda = 1$. Then $T(u,v) = \lambda (u,v)$ becomes $(u,v)=(v,u)$, which implies a $1$-eigenvector must have the form...?
- $\lambda = -1$. Then $T(u,v) = \lambda (u,v)$ becomes $(u,v) = (-v, -u)$, which implies a $(-1)$-eigenvector must have the form...?

Since we have found two distinct eigenvalues, then indeed the eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$, and you have hopefully computed the corresponding eigenvectors as above.